# KendoUI Grid - how to hide filter buttons?

Tags: kendo-grid

I have some filterable columns in that grid, I can't find any tips about how I can remove that filter buttons ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css

```
span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header.k-dropdown-operator {
display: none;
}
```